# sh fails to write content to a file

Tags: php, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am using [magephp](https://github.com/andres-montanez/Magallanes/blob/master/src/Runtime/Runtime.php#L428) for the PHP deployment to the server. That script executes commands on the remote server using the `sh -c \" ... \"`. Everything worked fine until I wanted to write some content to the file on the remote server.

For that purpose I have tried to run the `echo 'foobar' > test.txt` command which apparently fails because of the delimiters `\"` that wrap around the command. What's interesting I am able to write the file to the content if I execute the command using non-escaped delimiters, i.e. `"`. See the working example below:

```
$ sh -c "echo 'foobar' > test.txt"
```

This does not work however:

```
$ sh -c \"echo 'foobar' > test.txt\"
foobar: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
foobar: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Strange enough that after this command that failed I got `test.txt"` file created but without any content.

Any ideas?

Comment: Escaping the quotes prevents them from acting as quotations. Don't do that.

Comment: The redirection is being done by the original shell. The file is empty because `sh` got an error, so it didn't print anything.

Comment: @Inian Apparently the backslashes are in the `magephp` script.

Comment: Passing nested quotes through `ssh` is tricky. You need to deal with both ssh's parsing of the arguments and the remote shell's parsing.

Comment: Indeed the backslashes are in the ```magephp``` script and when I tried to remove them the other commands started to fail, so I don't want to ask to change that (would be a BC break too).

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to wrap (hide) the redirection into a script:

- `/my/path/print.sh`

  ```
  echo '$1' > $2
  ```
- call from magephp:

  ```
  sh -c \" /my/path/print.sh 'foobar' test \"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the contribution. We have created the issue at the mage project and the command has been reworked to not use `\"` as delimiters. This way no escaping trickery is needed at all.

https://github.com/andres-montanez/Magallanes/issues/350